# Parse a massive JSON array of hashes

Tags: json, ruby, parsing, jsonparser, yajl

I am trying to parse a JSON object that consists of a few hashes and a massive array of hashes (sometimes 300,000 hashes inside the array, 200MB). Here is an example of the JSON object. I need to parse hash by hash inside the array `report_datasets`.

https://api.datacite.org/reports/0cb326d1-e3e7-4cc1-9d86-7c5f3d5ca310

```
{ report_header: {report_id: 33738, report_name: "Report first"},
  report_datasets: [
  {dataset_id:1, yop:1990},
  {dataset_id:2, yop:2007},
  {dataset_id:3,  yop:1983},
  .
  {dataset_id:578999,yop:1964},
  ]
}
```

In every approach I tried, including a few approaches using `yajl-ruby` and `json-streamer`, my app is killed. When I use `parse_chunk`,

```
def parse_very_large_json
        options= {symbolize_keys:false}
        parser = Yajl::Parser.new(options)
        parser.on_parse_complete = method(:print_each_item)

        report_array = parser.parse_chunk(json_string) 
end

def print_each_item report
      report["report-datasets"].each do |dataset|
      puts “this is an element of the array“
      puts dataset
    end
end
```

parsing happens, but eventually again it is killed.

The problem seems to be that there is not much difference between `Yajl::Parser.new().parse` and `Yajl::Parser.new().parse_chunk` in both approaches that are killed.

How can one parse the elements of such a massive JSON array efficiently without killing the rails app?

Comment: any error message from the OS when your app is killed?

Comment: nada @emaillenin, I have been running my tests with `rspec` and I can see the whole parser printing each element of the array til suddenly I get a `Killed` stdout. that's it.

Comment: can you try Oj gem?

Comment: that seems like an option but i need to give it a read. It seems a more like building your own parser http://www.ohler.com/oj/doc/Oj/ScHandler.html . have you use it ?

Comment: Did you tried approach described in [`Ruby: reading, parsing and forwarding large JSON files in small chunks (i.e. streaming)`](https://coderwall.com/p/l1omyw/ruby-reading-parsing-and-forwarding-large-json-files-in-small-chunks-i-e-streaming) article? It uses Oj::ScHandler parser but [`Yajl::FFI::Parser` also supports streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52876204/4950680)

Comment: I'm going to try the `Oj`approach. I have read the `Yajl::FFI::Parser` approach but this seem mostly to rely on getting the json object from a request (EventMachine).     That is not my case. I already have the json object, I just need to parse the json object.